# Ionic Api call to check if token is expired

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am building an ionic 3 app and I want to know if the token is expired by calling an api. I want to ask the user for password if the token is expired. Is it a bad way to call the api in a setInterval()?I mean:

```
   this.setInt = setInterval(() => { 
   this.storage.get('api_token').then((val) => {
     //calling the api and checking token 
   });
   });
```

Is there a better way to do it in ionic 3?

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49559546/4399281 , you can use angular2-jwt for token authentification, it works great

Comment: well, yeah, that's not the way to do it. Look for angular2-jwt, gives you a great help with a lot of things, including token expiring

Comment: Definitely a bad practice (to use interval). Better is to tie checks for token validity to lifecycle hooks or on certain events like data query or login etc

Comment: Can you please elaborate more(links..) @SergeyRudenko